# How to scroll a <li> while appending it into group of <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a Div Container which holds 4 `<li>`

What I am doing is prepend a `<li>` into the `<ul>` and remove the last `<li>`

I did that quite easily using

```
$('#news-ul li:last').remove()
$('#news-ul').prepend(str);  //str contains a <li>
```

I want to have scroll effect when the `<li>` is prepending. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm getting you right, but if I am, I'd first create a new element:

```
var newEle = $(str);
```

Then prepend it, hide and animate

```
$('#news-ul').prepend(newEle);
$(newEle).hide().slideDown();
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit, more code:**

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ If I were to recreate the twitter effect it would probably be:

```
$('#news-ul').prepend(newEle);
$(newEle).fadeTo(0,0.01,function(){
    $(this).hide().slideDown('normal',function(){
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

A quick description, first we add the element as before, then fade it out to 1% opacity in 0 seconds (at 0 opacity it has no height), then, when we know its faded, we issue a callback, hiding the element completely, issue the slidedown with a normal speed, when done sliding, we issue another callback fading it in.

**Warning:** The above code is untested, use at your own risk ^^

Comment: Can we get the twitter like effect (Top TWeets at homepage)

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at

[jQuery.ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin